# Calling function every n second javascript game

Tags: javascript, game-loop, timer

I making a game and I want to call a function that runs every random second to spawn something every time. I've seen some posts that said to use the `setInterval()` function to keep track of the time but I don't know where to implement it because I'm using the `requestAnimationFrame()` to loop the game. I also tried to implement it in the update function of the classes but it doesn't seem to work.

This is my main with the loop

```
import Game from '/src/game.js';

let canvas = document.getElementById('main');
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

const WIDTH_SCREEN = 800;
const HEIGTH_SCREEN = 600;

let game = new Game(WIDTH_SCREEN, HEIGTH_SCREEN);   
game.start();

function loop() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, WIDTH_SCREEN, HEIGTH_SCREEN);

    game.update(ctx);

    requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}

window.addEventListener("keydown", (event) => game.controller.keyListener(event));
window.addEventListener("keyup", (event) => game.controller.keyListener(event));
requestAnimationFrame(loop);
```

Comment: What is the goal? Execute every n ms, throughout lifetime? Have you tried to put it next to other game/window setup code?

Comment: I recommend separating the game logic from the rendering logic, it's bad practice to keep them together

Comment: What you could do is in your game class add a property called tickNum or something, and set it equal to a random number between m and n. Then every time the game loop is called subtract one from that property and if it equals 0 spawn a new object and add another random value to the tickNum property.

Comment: That worked perfectly thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass an optional `time` parameter to your `window.requestAnimationFrame()` callback (`loop()` in this case), and it will pass in the current amount of time (in milliseconds) since the first frame.
You can create a timer object to take advantage of that:

```
const Timer = (event, interval = 0) => {
    let last = 0;
    let total = 0;
    return {
        set interval(newInterval)
        {
            interval = newInterval;
        },
        update(time = 0) {
            total += time - last;
            if (total >= interval) {
                event(this);
                total = 0;
            }
            last = time;
        }
    };
};
```

Now you can do this:

```
const fooLogger = Timer((timer) => {
    console.log('foo!');
    timer.interval = 1000 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
}, 1500);
function loop(time) {
    requestAnimationFrame(loop);
    fooLogger.update(time);
}
requestAnimationFrame(loop);
```

And this should log "foo!" every 1 - 2 seconds.
Update: The question specified a variable interval, that has been added.